# When using Boost::Geometry to calculate the area of a Polygon, what are the units in?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

Using the [area example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/area/area_1.html) from boost.org, the spherical_equatorial method outputs a value of "0.339837". What are these units? The documentation states,

> The units are the square of the units used for the points defining the surface.

My goal is to get a rough approximation of area on the surface of the earth.  I would expect a triangle polygon with side lengths of 45 deg near the equator to be closer to 14E6 km^2.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

int main()
{
    // Calculate the area of a spherical equatorial polygon
    bg::model::polygon<bg::model::point<float, 2, bg::cs::spherical_equatorial<bg::degree>>> sph_poly;
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0,0 45,45 0,0 0))", sph_poly);
    auto area = bg::area(sph_poly);
    std::cout << "Area: " << area << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
// Output: "Area: 0.339837"
```

Comment: Your *input* units are degrees, so the area will most like be in [square degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_degree). (But the value looks wrong, if that is the case.)

Comment: Conversion to square metres [can be found here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/28156/203568).

Comment: in boost/geometry/formulas/area_formulas_hpp, there is a trapazoidal formula that is converting the values to radians.  If I use the formula `(radians^2)/2` I get a reasonable answer.  e.g. `((pi/4)^2)/2 = 0.3084`. I don't know if this works for all inputs so it could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an area strategy that also defines the radius of the sphere (the default value is `1`, that is why you are getting an area of `0.339837`).
The example below returns the area you were expecting.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

int main()
{
    using CT = float;
    // an approximation of the radius of the Earth is 6371 km
    bg::strategies::area::spherical<CT> spherical_earth(6371);
    bg::model::polygon<bg::model::point
    <
        CT, 2,
        bg::cs::spherical_equatorial<bg::degree>>
    > sph_poly;
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0,0 45,45 0,0 0))", sph_poly);
    auto area = bg::area(sph_poly, spherical_earth);
    std::cout << "Area: " << area << " km^2" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
// Output: "Area: 1.37939e+07"
```

See also the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/area/area_2_with_strategy.html) of Boost Geometry.